# LP programming of a Markov Decision Model

Tags: markov-decision-process

I am doing my thesis and I encounter the following issue last weeks, without solving it yet: I am trying to formulate a Markov Decision Process as an LP formulation, considering 2 items. (In the picture you can see the general formulation for one item). If we consider p1 the probability of item1 to stay in state i and 1-p1 to degrade to state i+1 (the same for p2 which is the probability of item2), how should I formulate the common transition matrix ? (both items degrade)

[image]